# Domain of Riemann integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

If given that a function $f$ is Riemann Integrable on $[a,b]$, is it necessary for the domain of $f$ to be $[a,b]$ or could the domain of $f$ be a set $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with $[a,b] \subset D$?

Comment: This sounds like a "difference that makes no difference", since the definition of the Riemann integral of $f$ on $[a,b]$ only involves the values $f(x)$ for $x \in [a,b].$ Maybe you could provide more context, such as where or how you think this distinction might be relevant?

Comment: You may define it for bounded sets $D$. If $D\subseteq [a, b]$ define $g(x) =f(x), x\in D$ and $g(x) =0,x\in[a,b]\setminus D$. Then we can use definition $\int_D f=\int_a^b g$.

Comment: @ Dave L. Renfro When you have the vector space of Riemann integrable functions on [a,b], I wasn't sure whether the functions in this vector space all have domain [a,b] or whether their domains can be something different.

Comment: *I wasn't sure whether* --- You would want all the functions to have the same domain, which could be $[a,b]$ or a fixed larger set containing $[a,b],$ simply due to usual conventions in assembling together functions as vectors for a vector space. I suppose the domains could vary, but one needs to be careful in stating exactly how the vector operation of sum is defined (and make sure that if one defines the domain of the sum as the intersection of the domains of the two functions being added, that there is a "sum" function with exactly that intersection-of-domains as its domain in the space).